# Using Javascript to POST xml to api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to post XML data and then do a redirect to the current page, but I can't seem to get it to work.

When I do this:

```
<form action="http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml" method="post">
```

it works and posts the data to the website that I want it to.

However, it leads the user to an XML page so I want to post it and then have it redirect to my current contact form page and have a success message of some kind.

I've tried using:

```
  function loadXMLDoc()
  {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

I don't get any errors in my console, but it does not post to the the freshdesk website like I want it to. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take the data from the form and send it in the request.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example on how to post with jQuery:

```
var data = 
    '<helpdesk_ticket>' +
    '<description>This is a test</description>' +
    '<email>sample@example.com</email>' + 
    '</helpdesk_ticket>'
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'text',
    username: 'username1',
    password: 'password1',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, tranStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(
            'Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + jqXHR.statusText + '. ' +
            'Response: ' + jqXHR.responseText
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tested my script on a different domain and it works (http://jsfiddle.net/U47Nw/) onehouse.freshdesk.com does not allow Cross-Domain requests

Comment: thanks for the reply but i get this error message when trying to implement that code XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @RickyAhn onehouse.freshdesk.com does not allow you to post data to their page because they do not have the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header set. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: do you think somewhere in the code i have to add the api key and password? would that be the issue?

Comment: @RickyAhn I cannot see the header in the Response. It could be that we are getting the 406 error response because of missing parameters and the header is not being added. You should try to set the required parameters in the request and see if it accepts a CORS POST.

Comment: @RickyAhn here is the API documentation: http://freshdesk.com/api/tickets/ticket/#create-a-ticket

Comment: @MarcoBettiolo why did you set `crossDomain: true`? that's the default value of that option when url is cross-domain.

Comment: @MarcoBettiolo Thanks for the info i checked out the API docs but im still super new to web development and having trouble understanding it

Comment: @RickyAhn Reading the docs you can POST cross domain but you need to specify the username/password or the API key

Comment: @RickyAhn here I updated the script to support passing the username and password fields: http://jsfiddle.net/8FWww/

Comment: @KevinB because I haven't read the jQuery docs :) Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MarcoBettiolo thanks for all your indepth help....it is helping me understand it a bit more....but i'm still getting the same error after passing in the username and password with either the api key with the default password of "X" or my correct username and password....i still get the XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. contacts?oid=00DU0000000I430&retURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ironridge.com&email=ma…tributes%5D%5Bdescription_html%5D=asfsadf&00NU0000002xpYP=&submit=Submit:1

Comment: @RickyAhn From the docs it seems that with the api key you have to provide a blank password.

Comment: @MarcoBettiolo hmmmm tried using a blank password.....i tried using username and password.....i tried using api key still getting the access control allow origin error........maybe it does not like ajax calls to the server?

Comment: @RickyAhn Reading at the docs it should support CORS POST request. I don't know the specifics of their API.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged jQuery, here's a jQuery solution which should work (I did not test it):

```
$.post("http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml", {
   // any parameters here 
}, function(data) {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=data;
})
```

You still have to specify the parameters, but as you did not provide your form html, I left it empty.
Also have a look at the api: [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: thanks for the reply when i tried it out i got this error in the console XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.xml. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Yeah, I did not think about the cross domain .. try @MarcoBettiolo's solution, which does exactly the same, but should work for cross-site requests. Or you upload it, then it might work.